# Bot Reminding events in one Google calendar

Tags: google-hangouts

I really find it weird Google doesnt have this as a built in (or maybe I haven't seen) A chatbot that can remind events added to acertain Google calendar.

Does this exist or is there a simple way to create it?

Comment: Asking for tools, libraries, tutorials, or off-site resources recommendation is off-topic in here

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is by publishing your events calendar and having a bot subscribe to it. That way it could send you an email/SMS or some other reminder.

I’ve used IFTT in the past to flash my lights if I forget to leave for an event, trouble is it doesn’t tell me what the event is till I pick up my phone & read the alert.